# ¿Como instalar automáticamente una extensión en Firefox?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, terminal, firefox, firefox-webextensions

**Hola**

Tengo la necesidad de poder instalar una **extensión** que hice para **Firefox** en ubuntu pero sin un **terminal gráfico**, así que necesito poder instalar la extensión sin la necesidad de **la interacción del usuario.**

Quiero hacer esto porque estoy **trabajando con dockers** y no tengo una **interfaz gráfica** para poder interactuar con mi contenedor que tiene la **imagen del sistema Ubuntu**. Y, por lo tanto, no puedo usar más allá de los comandos para interactuar con ubuntu en mi contenedor docker.

intente utilizar el [comando de Firefox:](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Mozilla/Opciones_de_linea_de_Comandos)

> firefox -install-global-extension /ruta/a/extension

Pero también requiere **interacción del usuario** para que pueda aceptar la instalación de la extensión.

Encontré esto [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73474/how-to-install-firefox-addon-from-command-line-in-scripts) pero no entiendo cómo hacer que la instalación **sea automática** porque cargar **.xpi** a la carpeta con las extensiones **no se instala en Firefox.**

Comment: No creo que sea posible, requerirá siempre de interacción con el usuario si no básicamente estarías brincando sus privilegios.

Comment: Claro, los virus informáticos también necesitan que el usuario no intervenga, bienvenido al desdichado mundo de los atacantes, que deben engañar al usuario para hacerle cree que su extensión es *legit*. XD. Lo que intentas hacer nunca lo lograrás, al menos no con una versión de Firefox legal. Saludos

Comment: Gracias amigo pero ya que mi proyecto es personal puedo manejar el firefox e instalar mi extensión y luego mudar mi firefox a mis contenedores ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi proyecto es **personal** por lo tanto la solucion es simplemente exportar mi extension .xpi y luego instalarla en mi **navegador firefox** en **ubuntu** para despues trasladar mi firefox de mi **ubuntu principal (Host)** a mis **contenedores ubuntu** y asi tendria ya la extensión instalada automáticamente en cada navegador **en cada contenedor del Docker.**